# regex to find 3 instances of letter in a row php

Tags: php, regex

I am working with a third party API and they have certain rules for the passwords passed on to  their system. One of them is the following:

*Does not contain the same letter/number three or more times in a row. (e.g., aaa123would fail for three instances of "a" in a row, but a1a2a3 would pass).*

I have tried looking for a solution but have not been able to find one. Could anybody help me with a solution to this. I am a php developer but not very clued up on creating a regex from scratch.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something like `'~(.)\1\1~'`

Comment: [`/(.)\g1{2,}/`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php)

Comment: Are you trying to match 3 consecutive characters/letters or trying to reject a string containing 3 consecutive characters/letters?

Comment: Unless you add more requirements for the password, its easier to **match** an errant password. `bResult = bMatched ? false : true;`

Comment: Jerry, I will be rejecting the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
preg_match('/^(?!.*([a-z\d])\1{2})/i', $password)
```

See [back references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) and [assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Answer (score 4):

You need backreferences.

```
/(.)\1\1/
```

`\1` means "whatever was captured in the first set of parentheses."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\1` reference to a `([a-zA-Z])` group:

```
/([a-zA-Z])\1{2}/
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lU4zC8)

Comment: Is it possible so, to reference a second content of parentheses with `\2`? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the number after the backslash refers to the index of the group you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the Demo Joeytje50 - will come in handy